# How to avoid downloading js files and authentication ember SPA

Tags: performance, ember.js, coffeescript

We have an ember single page application. On a specific page, while clicking on a hyperlink, I want to open a specific route in the new window.

The problem here is, it starts downloading all the js files (main.js) and authenticating the session and then only it is loading the route. This is taking too much time and giving a poor user experience. Since the hyperlink can be clicked only when the user is already logged in, is there a way to avoid downloading all the js files and authentication in ember? Something like a child window of the current window, so that the route will be loaded immediately.

Answer (score 1):

> is there a way to avoid downloading all the js files

They should be cached by the browser unless you have your server set headers to not cache your JS files. 
But maybe the files are loaded from cache but the delay you are experiencing is the parsing and execution of your scripts. This cannot be avoided with a SPA.

You could shorten the perceived  delay by using server side rendering via [FastBoot](https://www.ember-fastboot.com/quickstart). This will mean the route is immediately rendered, but the user won't be able to interact with it fully until all of the client-side scripts have been executed.

> authentication in ember

I don't think this adds much delay as it should just be checking a cookie or HTTP header as you are already authenticated in another window.

> Something like a child window of the current window, so that the route will be loaded immediately.

As you have a SPA, you should try to avoid opening a new window as everything is already loaded in the current one. And the user can easily return to the previous page via the browser back button and this too should be almost instantaneous.

Is there a particular business reason why it has to be in a new window?

Comment: Is there a particular business reason why it has to be in a new window?

The people have to see the details of multiple entities in parallel in order to compare and showing it to the clients for selling.

I'm trying now to load it in the modal window